# Unable to import external JS library into web application

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a basic web application which converts markdown in a `<textarea>` into HTML. For this I wanted to use the PageDown library, which SO also uses: https://code.google.com/archive/p/pagedown/wikis/PageDown.wiki.

I downloaded the PageDown source code, extracted it and placed it inside the top-level directory containing my HTML/JS files. So the directory structure looks like this:

```
.
├── index.html
├── main.js
├── pagedown
│   ├── LICENSE.txt
│   ├── Markdown.Converter.js
│   ├── Markdown.Editor.js
│   ├── Markdown.Sanitizer.js
│   ├── README.txt
│   ├── demo
│   ├── local
│   ├── node-pagedown.js
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── resources
│   └── wmd-buttons.png
└── style.css
```

Then I tried to load it in the following way:

`main.js`:

```
import { Converter } from 'Markdown.Converter.js'

var text = "**Markdown rocks**"

var converter = new Markdown.Converter();
var html = converter.makeHtml(text);
```

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="module" src="main.js" defer></script>
    <script type="module" src="./pagedown/Markdown.Converter.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./pagedown/Markdown.Sanitizer.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./pagedown/Markdown.Editor.js"></script>
    <title>Text</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea name="" id="textinput" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I'm running the code in Chrome using the VSCode Live Server extension. I get the following output:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "Markdown.Converter.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
Markdown.Sanitizer.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Converter')
    at Markdown.Sanitizer.js:8:28
    at Markdown.Sanitizer.js:108:3
(anonymous) @ Markdown.Sanitizer.js:8
(anonymous) @ Markdown.Sanitizer.js:108
Markdown.Editor.js:92 Uncaught ReferenceError: Markdown is not defined
    at Markdown.Editor.js:92:5
    at Markdown.Editor.js:2301:3
```

So I tried changing the path to the `Markdown.*` scripts to `/pagedown/Markdown.*.js`, and `pagedown/Markdown.*.js`, but I got the same error for both.

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Literal answer

You need to alter the `import` path in your `main.js` to the relative location of `Markdown.Converter.js`:

```js
import { Converter } from './pagedown/Markdown.Converter.js';
```

### 2. Module error

But if you try this now, you will get some error like:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './pagedown/Markdown.Converter.js' does not provide an export named 'Converter'

### 3. The fix

And this is because `Markdown.Converter.js` is not an ESM JavaScript file. We can tell this because it has no [`export` statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#exporting_module_features).

#### 3.1 ESM to non-ESM

What we have to appeal to instead is the "old-fashioned" version of loading the script, as these scripts are setting their library code into the "global" scope. We can see this in `Markdown.Converter.js` since in the first few lines of it, it has this statement not wrapped in any other scope:

```js
var Markdown;
```

So, to give these scripts access to the global scope such that `main.js` can "access" their code, we need to remove the `type="module"` from these scripts, since (as per [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#other_differences_between_modules_and_standard_scripts)):

> Module-defined variables are scoped to the module unless explicitly attached to the global object.

So now your `index.html` should be

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="./pagedown/Markdown.Converter.js"></script>
    <script src="./pagedown/Markdown.Sanitizer.js"></script>
    <script src="./pagedown/Markdown.Editor.js"></script>
    <title>Text</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea name="" id="textinput" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

##### 3.1.1 ESM script loading note

Note: as per the same [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#other_differences_between_modules_and_standard_scripts) mentioned above:

> There is no need to use the `defer` attribute (see [`<script>` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attributes)) when loading a module script; modules are deferred automatically.

We don't need the `defer` on the `main.js` script.

#### 3.2 Remove the import

Now `Markdown` is in the global scope available to `main.js` and we no longer need the `import` statement so your entire `main.js` should now look like:

```js
var text = "**Markdown rocks**"

var converter = new Markdown.Converter();
var html = converter.makeHtml(text);
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, you've provided the fix and also the context I needed. Thank you! I did eventually realise I didn't need to import and it started working correctly, but I didn't appreciate why.